# convert syslog file into csv

Tags: bash, shell, csv, syslog

`$cat syslog* | grep -a "CRON" | grep "CMD"`

```
Jun 24 22:17:01 ubuntu1804-template CRON[7772]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)  
Jun 24 23:17:01 ubuntu1804-template CRON[7779]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)  
2021-06-24T10:05:01.590200-07:00 ubuntu1804-template CRON[7772]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)  
2021-06-25T10:05:01.590200-07:00 ubuntu1804-template CRON[7772]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

I want to convert this into **csv file** with three column. `Hostname` column is being fetched from a `variable`
Expected output:

```
Date                                 Hostname             Message  
Jun 24 22:17:01                      $variable                     CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)  
Jun 24 23:17:01                      $variable                     CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)  
2021-06-24T10:05:01.590200-07:00     $variable                     CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)  
2021-06-25T10:05:01.590200-07:00     $variable                     CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

I'm trying with awk but the date format is screwing the output

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# set in you need
variable='ubuntu1804-template'

cat syslog* | grep -a "CRON" | grep "CMD" | awk -F"$variable" -vhostname="$variable" 'BEGIN {printf("%-40s %-30s %s\n", "Date","Hostname","Message")} {split($NF, rstArr, "CMD"); printf("%-40s %-30s %s\n", $1, hostname, "CMD"rstArr[2])}'
```

You could format your output by `printf("%-40s %-30s %s\n", $1..)`, this **`%-40s %-30s %s\n`** will define the line format.